# How to set netbeans 7.2 as my default PHP IDE on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php, ide, netbeans, file-association

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit ... I have installed XAMPP and Netbeans 7.2 IDE. The problem is I can't open any PHP file using Netbeans IDE and when I click "open with" I can't find Netbeans within the displayed app

How to set Netbeans 7.2 as my default PHP files IDE?

Answer (score 6):

Just open the following path,

```
cd /usr/share/applications/
```

Find netbeans.desktop file

```
ls -al | grep netbeans
```

Edit netbeans.desktop file

```
vim netbeans <version>
Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans" %U
```

Just add **%U** at the end of Exec.

Now goto any file, right click properties->open with, there you see netbeans.
Now set it as default.

Comment: It prefect answer, for all apps %U add to open with applist  or for other apps is different ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is the perfect way but it works fine:

1. I assume you installed Netbeans manually so you will have to create a `.desktop` file like this:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=<program name maybe Netbeans 7>
   Exec=<then command to run program maybe /opt/netbeans/run.sh or some thing so > %U
   Type=Application
   ```

   This is the essential information, you can add more details such Icon and categories later.

   **NOTE:** the `%U` is very important after the Exec command without it the application won't appear in `other applications` list.
2. After that, put the file in `/usr/share/applications/` (need root privileges) and it should appear in the Dash when you type the name.
3. Now go to any `.php` file, right click on it and choose `properties -> open with -> show other application -> select your app`.
4. Enjoy coding!

Comment: at the first i just wanna thank you , but would you tell me how to do what you told me above in steps ? i'm new to ubuntu :D, thank you again

Comment: the answer is really helpful. But I've a question, why do I have to make a `desktop entry`? Its been already available in `Dash` when I search.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the tutorial "How to set netbeans as default PHP IDE on ubuntu" at This page http://www.phpides.com/news/php-ide/how-to-set-netbeans-as-default-php-ide-on-ubuntu
It is from http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Even though it's pretty clear you're not trying to conceal this information, we still require that you [explicitly disclose](http://askubuntu.com/faq#promotion) that you're linking to your own blog, when doing so. At minimum, please edit your post to include such disclosure. In addition, [it would be even better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Netbeans open terminal and write

`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

write the below code

```
application/x-php=netbeans-7.3.desktop
```

and save the file.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Netbeans open the terminal and run:

```
sudoedit /usr/share/applications/netbeans.desktop`
```

And add

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=NetBeans
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans" %U
Icon=/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/nb/netbeans.png
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Keywords=development;Java;IDE;platform;javafx;javase;
```

Note: Don't forget to replace Netbeans path